# Is there a way to use over with order by clause in linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to get the running sum for ordered value so I need replicate this query in linq

```
SELECT  sum(number) over (order by number)

FROM tableName
```

do you know a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could work:

Edited (I've tried your query out and I think this is you are looking for)

```
List<TableName> tableNames = new List<TableName> {
    new TableName { Number = 2},
    new TableName { Number = 4},
    new TableName { Number = 3},
    new TableName { Number = 3},
    new TableName { Number = 2},
    new TableName { Number = 3},
    new TableName { Number = 4},
    new TableName { Number = 4},
    new TableName { Number = 4},
    new TableName { Number = 4}
};

IEnumerable<int> runningSum = tableNames.Select(r => (tableNames.Where(ri => ri.Number <= r.Number).Sum(rii => rii.Number))).OrderBy(num => num);
```

Result:

```
4
4
13
13
13
33
33
33
33
33
```